# Magento 2 referenceBlock Location in layout File

Tags: magento2, layout, locations

In **default.xml** of the **magento/module-theme** Module we have the following referenceBlock on Line 19:

```
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

In which layout file is the block with Name 'name="top.links"' defined ? It is referred, so it has to be defined in some layout XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the layout file that the `top.links` block is defined

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

Comment: Search for 'top.links'. Line 43?